taking char. by char. input to make a string in c
so i did try it with using a for loop but every single time my output skips the value of index 0 and i just dont understand why....
here is my code :
// take char by char input and print it as string

#include <stdio.h>

void input(){
    printf("this program takes char by char input for string\n");
    int length;
    printf("provide us with the total length of the string : ");
    scanf("%d",&length);
    char arr[length];
    char placeholder;
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
        if(i==length){
             arr[i]='\0';
        }
        printf("input char[%d] : ",i);
        scanf("%c",&placeholder);
        printf("\n");
        arr[i]=placeholder;
        }
}

int main(){
    input();
}

the output im getting :
this program takes char by char input for string
provide us with the total length of the string : 10
input char[0] :       // it got skipped
input char[1] :       // this is where i can enter value

if(i==length) This condition cannot possibly be true. It is inside for(int i=0;i<length;i++) loop. so i<length is true inside. You ar reassigning arr[i] anyway later, so this is doubly useless.

When asked for length you entered 10{newline}, but %d only reads the 10 and leaves the {newline} buffered, so when you subsequently use %c it reads the {newline} for 'char[0]' and then your next input into 'char[1]etc. I'm sure this is a dupe but don't have one bookmarked. @n.m. also if you did accessarr[length]` that would be outside the valid bounds of the array causing Undefined Behavior

As for your immediate question, the first character you read is the newline that is left in the input buffer after the number. I recommend never using scanf. Read input lines with fgets, then parse them.

@n.m.couldbeanAI Never is a long time.  fgets() is weak when reading user input that may contain null characters.  scanf("%999[^\n]%n", ...) is a building block to read such.  Standard C still lacks a real good line input function.

@chux? User input contains null characters in the middle of a line? Then everything after that is ignored. User wants something else? Close, wontfix.If valid user input is supposed to contain embedded null characters, then it's mot lines. It's binary data.

@n.m.couldbeanAI, C Std lib has <A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into lines, each "line" consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character. Whether the last line requires a terminating new-line character is implementation-defined.> with no special consideration of null characters. fgets() doesn't ignore input after reading a null character, but reads & saves until a '\n'. Text streams using UTF16, UTF32, commonly contain null bytes, though not null characters.

@n.m.couldbeanAI ... It isn't a null character/byte makes input non-text, it is that using C's string to handle such input is restrictive. I can understand one's reluctance to want to deal with embedded '\0' in C - it is rather pesky.  Other approaches with length/data strings handle this better.

For starters this if statement within the for loop
for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
    if(i==length){
         arr[i]='\0';
    }
    //...

is never executed due to the condition of the for loop. Moreover in any case this if statement is invalid because the valid range of indices for the array is [0, length). That is using an index equal to the value of length results in overwritting memory outside the array.
Secondly this call of scanf
scanf("%c",&placeholder);

reads also the new line character '\n' that stored in the input buffer after pressing the Enter key.
To skip white space characters including the new line character '\n' you should use the following conversion specification
scanf(" %c",&placeholder);
   

Pay attention to the leading space in the format string.
Also bear in mind that you should check whether the value of the variable length was inputed and whether it is gretaer than zero.  For example something like
if ( scanf("%d",&length) == 1 && length > 0 )
{
   char arr[length];
   //...
}
else
{
   //...
}

Though in any case it would be better to declare the variable length as having an unsigned integer type (unsigned int or size_t) instead of the signed integer type int.

Thank u for explaining the answer in such detail. it made me happy. Thank u for helping me and have a great day :)

@Rudraksh_pd No at all. We, beginners, should help each other.:)

"it would be better to declare the variable length as having an unsigned integer type (unsigned int or size_t) instead of the signed integer type int." --> Maybe not. Consider unsigned len; if ( scanf("%u", &len) == 1 && len > 0 ) { char arr[len];   //... }.  Should user enter "-1\n", code will attempt arr[UINT_MAX] -- certainly a troublesome case.  int len; if ( scanf("%d", &len) == 1 && len > 0 ) ... does not have this trouble.  unsigned would make sense with if ( scanf("%u", &len) == 1 && len > 0 && len <= SOME_SANE_LIMIT_LIKE_1000).

@chux If you will enter a negative number for the conversion specifier u then the call of scanf will fail.

"enter a negative number for the conversion specifier u then the call of scanf will fail." --> the C spec does not agree. "u Matches an optionally signed decimal integer, whose format is the same as expected for the subject sequence of the strtoul"  Try #include <stdio.h> int main() {  unsigned u = 42;  int i = scanf("%u", &u);   printf("%d %u\n", i, u); } and enter "-1\n".  I get 1 4294967295.  strtoul("-1", 0, 10) nicely returns a positive with errno still 0.

strtoul() What is the correct return value for very "negative" strings? may help.   We, beginners, should help each other.

@chux You are right. I thought that scanf will not allow to enter the minus sign.
